# Loop through JSON response fails

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I get JSON response from a server:

```
[{"id":605,"vote":1},{"id":606,"vote":-1},{"id":611,"vote":1},{"id":609,"vote":-1}]
```

Then I try to loop through results and get objects properties:

```
success: 
function (data) {
$.each(data, function() {
$.each(this, function(i, v) {
alert(i+v);
});    
});
}
```

But somehow my code fails and no alert is shown. What am I doing wrong guys?

Comment: use `console.log(data)` to output the object structure, and then check if you are accessing the objects the right way

Comment: Works here: http://jsfiddle.net/pztB5/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify `dataType` to `"json"` in your ajax request:

```
 $.ajax({
     //...
     dataType:"json",
     success://etc...
```

Comment: Silly me... The problem was that I didn't specify datatype as you mentioned. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are no parsing issues with the string being in correct JSON format, you could do:

```
function (data) {
$.each(data, function() {
 console.log(this.id);
console.log(this.vote);
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var data = [{"id":605,"vote":1},{"id":606,"vote":-1},{"id":611,"vote":1},{"id":609,"vote":-1}];
$.each(data, function( index, value ) {
  console.log( index + ": " + value.id + ", " + value.vote );
});
```