# Loop through json response not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

JSON:

```
[
{"name":"BH<sub>3</sub>",   "file": "BH3.js"},
{"name":"CFH<sub>3</sub>",  "file":"CFH3.js"},
{"name":"CH<sub>4</sub>",    "file":"CH4.js"},
{"name":"CO<sub>2</sub>",    "file":"CO2.js"},
{"name":"H<sub>2</sub>O",    "file":"H2O.js"},
{"name":"Pyridine",          "file":"PYRIDINE.js"}, 
{"name":"NH<sub>3</sub>",    "file":"NH3.js"},           
]
```

I'm trying to get this JSON and subsequently loop through it to create two new smaller objects ideally in the format:

New Object 1:

```
{"name":"BH<sub>3</sub>",
 "name":"CFH<sub>3</sub>",
 "name":"CH<sub>4</sub>",
 "name":"CO<sub>2</sub>",
 "name":"H<sub>2</sub>O",
 "name":"Pyridine",
 "name":"NH<sub>3</sub>"}
```

New Object 2:

```
{"file": "BH3.js",
 "file":"CFH3.js",
 "file":"CH4.js",
 "file":"CO2.js",
 "file":"H2O.js",
 "file":"PYRIDINE.js",
 "file":"NH3.js"}
```

So far I've hit a major roadblock. I use the follow ajax request to get the original JSON file -which works fine. However, nothing seems to happen in my basic success function which I'm tryin out a basic approach to looping through my original JSON.

I've tried numerous methods suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/733314/jquery-loop-over-json-result-from-ajax-success) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20403658/loop-through-json-response-fails), but nothing seems to work. I thought it might be firebug not working so I reinstalled it several times and even tried tweaking the prompts.tab_modal, but nothing changes.

```
$(window).bind("load", function(){
 $.ajax({
   url: "externalJS/MolecularArray.js",
   type: "GET",
   dataType:"json",
   async: true,
   success: function (data) {
     $.each(data, function() {
     $.each(this, function(n, f) {
        alert(n+f);
          });
         });       
       }
      });
    });
```

The GET JSON works, but no alerts come up in my browser or in console when console.log used instead.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your JSON is invalid; trailing comma.

Comment: Posted as an answer :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/A4a6L/1/

Comment: MAy b this http://jsfiddle.net/krunalp1993/2vJpG/1/

Comment: @KrunalPanchal I see what you're doing, but it doesn't seem to show anything on jsfiddle result

Comment: @EliiiFish Check in console

Comment: Is that what you wanted ??

Comment: Yeah very close, I modified it slightly and it works how I need, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON is invalid; trailing comma.